# Three.js Cube with different texture on each face. How to hide edges / vertices

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am trying to create a Cube in Three.js with a different image as texture on each face of the cube.

How can I hide the edges/vertices of the mesh?

Code:

```
var container, camera, scene, renderer, cube;

init();
animate();

function init(){
    container = document.getElementById('container');
    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
    camera.position.y = 150;
    camera.position.z = 500;
    scene.add( camera );

    var materials = [];
    for ( var i = 0; i < 6; i ++ ) {
        materials.push( new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'img/' + i + '.png') } ) );
    }

    cube = new THREE.Mesh( new THREE.CubeGeometry( 200, 200, 200, 5,5,5, materials ), new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial() );
    cube.position.y = 150;
    scene.add( cube );
    renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer();
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
    }

function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
    render();
}

function render(){
    cube.rotation.y += 0.005;
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
}
```

Comment: This code doesn't appear as though it would show edges... you would need to set a wireframe:true flag somewhere to see them. Could you post a live example of your code somewhere so we can see what you're talking about?

Comment: I would like to post an example on jsfiddle but it won’t work.

Comment: When I use `overdraw: true` in the for loop, it doesn’t show the edges anymore.
When I do not subdivide the mesh as EliSherer suggested, the faces of the cube shift in a strange way.
See https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/659

Answer (score 3):

change:

```
for ( var i = 0; i < 6; i ++ ) {
    materials.push( new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'img/' + i + '.jpg') } ) );
}
```

to:

```
for ( var i = 0; i < 6; i ++ ) {
    materials.push( new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'img/' + i + '.jpg'), overdraw: true } ) );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

change the line:

```
cube = new THREE.Mesh( new THREE.CubeGeometry( 200, 200, 200, 5,5,5, materials ), new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial() );
```

to:

```
cube = new THREE.Mesh( new THREE.CubeGeometry( 200, 200, 200, 1,1,1, materials ), new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial() );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using another renderer. Change this line:

```
 renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer();
```

to this one:

```
 renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
```