# Applying Textures to Non-Cube Polyhedra with Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, textures

I am using Three.js to generate a polyhedron with differing colors and text on each face, generated from a canvas element.  For now, I'm sticking with polyhedra for which Three.js includes native classes, but at some point, I'd like to branch out into more irregular shapes.

There are a number of examples available online (including StackOverflow posts, like [Three.js cube with different texture on each face](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17418118/three-js-cube-with-different-texture-on-each-face)) that explain how to do this with cubes.  I haven't succeeded in finding any samples that show the same technique applied to non-cubes, but for the most part, the same process that works for CubeGeometry also works for TetrahedronGeometry and so forth.

Here's a simplified version of the code I'm using to generate the polyhedron:

```
switch (shape) {
    case "ICOSAHEDRON" :

        // Step 1: Create the appropriate geometry.
        geometry = new THREE.IcosahedronGeometry(PolyHeatMap.GEOMETRY_CIRCUMRADIUS);

        // Step 2: Create one material for each face, and combine them into one big
        // MeshFaceMaterial.
        material = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(createMaterials(20, textArray));

        // Step 3: Pair each face with one of the materials.
        for (x = 0; face = geometry.faces[x]; x++)
        {
            face.materialIndex = x;
        }
        break;

     // And so on, for other shapes.
}

function createTexture (title, color) {
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");

    // Magical canvas generation happens here.

    var texture = new THREE.Texture(canvas);
    texture.needsUpdate = true;

    return new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ map : texture });
}

function createMaterials (numFacets, textArray)
{
    var materialsArray = [],
        material;

    for (var x = 0, xl = numFacets; x < xl; x++)
    {
        material = createTexture(textArray[x], generateColor(textArray[x]));
        material.side = THREE.DoubleSide;
        materials.push(oMaterial); 
    }

    return materials;
}
```

Cubes render perfectly using this technique, but with other polyhedra, the textures do not behave as expected:

[image: Icosahedron Example]

It's hard to explain precisely what's happening here.  Essentially, each face is displaying the correct texture, but the texture itself has been stretched and shifted as if to cover the entire polyhedron.  In other words - looking at the shape dead-on - the upper-left face is only showing the upper-left portion of its texture, the upper-right face is only showing the upper-right portion, and so on.

The faces on the opposite side of the polyhedron shows no texture detail at all; only colors.

I had no experience with 3D rendering prior to experimenting with Three.js, so I imagine that there's some step I'm missing that is handled automatically by CubeGeometry but not its sister classes.  I'd refer to other examples that have been posted, but most examples are rendering cubes, and those that don't are usually using solid colors.

What needs to happen for the textures on the non-cube shapes to be scaled and centered properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set new UVs.

I made a simple example how to do it, don't know if it's the best way.

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/9fy3j/1/)

Update

```
  geometry.faceVertexUvs[0] = [];

   for(var i = 0; i < geometry.faces.length; i++){                              

        // set new coordinates, all faces will have same mapping.            
        geometry.faceVertexUvs[0].push([
        new THREE.Vector2( 0,0 ),
        new THREE.Vector2( 0,1 ),
        new THREE.Vector2( 1,1),

        ]);
    }
```

Comment: How to make it so that the it covers whole face not 3 triangles ? like to make the image cover the star shaped faces only ?