# Applying different textures on a THREE.js OBJLoader loaded object

Tags: three.js

I have a square shape `.obj` model and 2 textures. How do I apply one texture on it's top face and another on rest of faces?

[image: Screenshot attached]

Comment: take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17418118/three-js-cube-with-different-texture-on-each-face

Comment: This isn't working. I've already tried this.

Comment: can you post a fiddle?

Comment: @gaitat I'll make and post a fiddle but think this is happening because I am using a custom geometry. is it possible to access faces of a custom geometry?

Comment: you mean `geometry.faces`; this gives you the array of faces.

Comment: @gaitat I also tried this but geometry.faces is undefined. here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/nishant_mishra/n4jsz944/1/

Comment: I only see one texture in the fiddle. Are you trying to apply the framed box texture as the "base" object texture and then the brick/whatever texture as the second texture?

Comment: `geometry.faces` is undefined because you're using `OBJLoader` which uses a `THREE.BufferGeometry` internally and not a `THREE.Geometry`. See my answer. You should really post this on `GameDev.SE` though...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a ton of ways to do what you're asking all with varying complexity depending on your needs. It looks like you want to apply **two materials** to your object and not two textures.

<sub>It looks this way because it seems you want the textures to be interchangeable so there's no way you're going to combine the images and keep resolution and `OBJ` & `THREE.Material` only support one set of `uv` attributes so you can't use a single material and multiple textures. So multiple materials it is...</sub>

#### Multiple materials

If you have two materials (2 `THREE.Material`s which correlate to 2 WebGL programs) then each face needs to know what material it's assigned to.

While the THREE.js multi material API has been in flux for quite a while and there are differences between `THREE.Geometry` and `THREE.BufferGeometry`, fortunately for you `THREE.OBJLoader` [supports material groups](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/examples/js/loaders/OBJLoader.js#L687) out of the box. To get this into THREE.js, you want to apply multiple materials in your 3D editor to your object and then export the OBJ to get everything. Doing it by hand is a little harder and requires calling `addGroup` as shown in the docs/the link above.

In THREE.js you simply pass in all the materials as an array to your object [demonstrated in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17427249/2759427). I also [updated your fiddle to do the same thing](https://jsfiddle.net/n4jsz944/4/). Relevant code shown below

```
var loadingManager = new THREE.LoadingManager();
var ObjLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader(loadingManager);
var textureLoader =  new THREE.TextureLoader(loadingManager);
//Material 1 with first texture
var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({map: textureLoader.load('https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/nvnacip8fhlrvm4/BoxUV.png?dl=0')});
//Material 2 with second texture
var material2 = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({map:
textureLoader.load('https://i.imgur.com/311w7oZ.png')});
ObjLoader.load(
    'https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/hiazgei0rxeirr4/cabinet30.obj?dl=0',
    function ( object ) {
        var geo = object.children[0].geometry;
        var mats = [material, material2];
        //These are just some random groups to demonstrate multi material, you need to set these up so they actually work for your object, either in code or in your 3D editor
        geo.addGroup(0,geo.getAttribute("position").count/2,0);
        geo.addGroup(geo.getAttribute("position").count/2,
        geo.getAttribute("position").count/2,1);
        //Mesh with multiple materials for material parameter
        obj = new THREE.Mesh(geo, mats);
        obj.position.y = 3;
    });
```