# three.js cube each face is a different texture

Tags: javascript, three.js, load, textures

```
        loader.load('IMAGE', (texture) => {
          const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
            map: texture,
          });
            var cubeGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(140, 140, 140);
            var cube = new THREE.Mesh(cubeGeometry, material);
            this.add(cube);
        });
```

I have this code that uses one texture for every face of the cube, but how can i adapt it so each face of the cube is a different texture?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17418118/three-js-cube-with-different-texture-on-each-face

Comment: Duplicate of [Three.js cube with different texture on each face](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17418118/three-js-cube-with-different-texture-on-each-face)